# Openlayers. How to remove last sketch if invalid

Tags: openlayers-2, events, wps

I can currently identify if a polygon is invalid through wps as per below code.
What I want to know is how to remove the last sketch polygon if it returns invalid?

To give you an idea, here is the code that is run on "sketchcomplete".

```
    farmpaddocks.events.on({
    sketchcomplete: function (e) {
    var poly = e.feature.geometry;//var of sketch geom

    //check if geom valid through wps
    wpsClient.execute({
    server: 'local', //from server address
    process: 'JTS:isValid', //wps function
    inputs: {
    geom: poly  //geom input for testing if valid
    },
    success: function(outputs) { 
    //on completion of testing check if false = invalid   geom
    if(outputs.result==false){
    $('#noti').append("Invalid Polygon").show(1000);
    $('#noti').css("color", "red");
    $('#noti').fadeOut(5000);
    draw.deactivate();
    }
    }               
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, solved my own question again. Seems to happen every time I make the decision to post.
Anyway, adding this line of code below the draw.deactivate(); solved the problem.

```
   farmpaddocks.removeFeatures(e.feature);
```